# Alignment in a GridLayout in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui

I'm trying to create a QGridLayout in PyQt4, and I can't figure out for the life of me how to change the alignment of the contents of the cells.  The docs say that any nonzero value for the 5th (6th counting self) argument means that the element being added doesn't fill the grid space, but so far I've not found any value that doesn't throw an error.  The Docs say to use a Qt.Alignment object, but I can't find the Qt module, and there's nothing of that nature in PyQt4.

Any suggestions?

When I try importing PyQt4.QtCore.Qt as suggested below, this is what happens:

```
#     import PyQt4.QtCore.Qt as Qt
# ImportError: No module named Qt #
```

is my install borked or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import PyQt4.QtCore.Qt
```

Won't work, since that last `Qt` isn't a module (it's most likely just a class providing namespacing). Do the following:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

Then for, say, right alignment:

```
QtCore.Qt.AlignRight
```

This is what you should pass to the *alignment* argument of `QGridLayout.addItem`

Comment: Instead of using `addItem()`, you can use `setAlignment()`.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt module that has the class `Alignment` is at `PyQt4.QtCore.Qt`

Comment: I may have to talk to whoever installed PyQt here if that is the case, because it errors out.